# Column Constraint or Sprint Constraint based on Epic Link Status

Tags: jira, scrum, jira-plugin, jira-agile, kanban

Trying to do a setup where I have a Kanban Board in JIRA Agile for managing Epics (working), and a Scrum Board where only task or user stories whose Epic Link ticket is "In Progress" can get worked on. A coworker says they had somethings similar at a previous company.

But Column Constraints seem limited to WIP limits. Can't find a to filter what tickets can get dragged into sprints. Even thought about just filtering what appears on the Active Scrum board but a '"Epic Status" = "In Progress"' filter only shows Epic's in Progress. From what I can tell "EPIC LINK" filter only lets you point to EMPTY or specific epics being linked to the task but not the state of that epic.

Does anyone know how you could go about this? Perhaps with an plugin? Or even just a filter that works for the status of a task's epic link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/cloud/overview) plugin gives you a JQL function called [linkedIssuesOf](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_linkedissuesof):

> linkedIssuesOf(subquery, link type)

This allows you to do something like:

> linkedIssuesOf("issuetype = Epic AND status = In Progress", "is epic of")

Which returns all the issues that are linked to an in progress epic. You then use that as an argument in a board filter.